# To put a click event on snippet of marker

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2, overlayitem

I have made an application in android for google map using mapView api2,I have tried the folowing code.In that i have made two markers and now i want to out click events on both the marker's "snippet"....not on marker..on snippet..please help me..

**manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mapviewdemo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>
  <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.mapviewdemo.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
          <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyCs4iErZHkoSk2lp_ah2XH70y0qCOaMxN8" />
    </application>
```

**Activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**main.java**

```
package com.example.mapviewdemo;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have followed all the steps in the below link

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

Add the below in manifest file

```
 <permission
    android:name="com.example.mapviewdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="com.example.mapviewdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment.html

Quoting from the above doc

Use this `MapFragment` only if you are `targeting API 12 and above`. Otherwise, use `SupportMapFragment`.

Your min sdk is 8. You should use Support Fragment.

```
<fragment
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:id="@+id/map"  
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Your activity must extend `FragmentActivity`

```
SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment)  getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
GoogleMap mMap = fm.getMap();
```

Make sure you have added support library

Also make sure you imported the below

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;  
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
```

Comment: i am facing problem when i am trying to set the api level of google-play-service-api lib project

Comment: what is the problem you are facing? have you referred to the google play services library project in your android project?

Comment: problem is whenever i click on "android" my eclipse is going to "not responding" mode...!

Comment: right click on your project. go to properties. click android and choose google api's. i guess there might be a problem with the way you have imported library project into eclipse